# Negative values extend beyond chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a [highcharts demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Siculus/Lcacj2L6/) that I created with multiple, separated bar charts contained within one chart. I need each bar chart to be a set width within the full chart, and this works fine as long as the charts contain only positive values. As soon as there are negative values, the values extend far beyond the expected width and interfere with the other charts.

The important code is probably in this section:

```
for (var seriesIndex = 0; seriesIndex < seriesPerRow.length; seriesIndex++)
{
    xAxes.push({
    categories: rowNames,
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tickWidth: 0,
        offset: -150 * seriesIndex
  });

  yAxes.push({
            gridLineWidth: 0,
        min: 0,
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
        enabled:false
        },
        width: 150,
        left: 150 + 150 * seriesIndex
  });
}
```

I would have expected the width of the yAxis to contain the values whether they are negative or positive but that is clearly not happening in the example.

Any ideas as to what can be done to keep those negative values within the constraints I'm setting? I understand that if this happens, I may need to adjust the axis locations a bit (for the record, this was the recommended method from the highcharts developers as to how to achieve my desired result).

Comment: Right now you have min of your y axis set to 0 and probably this is the reason why you have your problems. When you will remove min:0 from your code, all of your charts should have good width

Comment: You would need to translate your axis manually or make custom function responsible for moving your axes. Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/Lcacj2L6/5/